# sapply paste before at beginning of string

Tags: r, paste, sapply

So I have a vector

```
lizt <- c("a","b","c")

> lizt
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

and I can use sapply to paste characters **after** each element

```
lizt2 <- sapply(lizt,paste0, "$", USE.NAMES=F)

lizt2
[1] "a$" "b$" "c$"
```

now, how do I use a similar function to paste characters **before** each element, so I get

```
lizt3
[1] "^a$" "^b$" "^c$"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`paste` and `paste0` are vectorized, so you don't need `sapply`

```
paste0('^', lizt, '$')
## [1] "^a$" "^b$" "^c$"
```

Answer (score 5):

As [mnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385941/mnel) [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12362052/967840), you do not need to use `sapply` here, but if you want to anyway, you can create your own custom function to use with `sapply` like this:

```
> sapply(lizt, function(x) paste0("^", x, "$"), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
[1] "^a$" "^b$" "^c$"
```